# i forgot my password and it is now blocked how do I erase and restore if my iphone5c is offline?

Tags: iphone, icloud, restore, remote-control

I was half asleep when I changed the password into a 4-digit code, until my son tried all passwords ever used and found it disabled after several tries. I can't use itunes to connect to the phone as it asks me to respond using my phone that is now blocked! I went to icloud -- find my phone -- and chose erase iphone, but the device is offline. It does not connect to our wifi and cellular data.

What to do? Can apple support remotely wipe or erase my phone? I can supply all necessary info and documents to prove the phone is mine and not lost. Please, please help....

Comment: If the phone didn't connect to wifi or cellular data apple support can't remotely do anything.   My advice would be go to an Apple Store.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you got the documents that proves the legitimacy of your purchase, you can go to the closest Apple Retail Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider.

Find them here:
https://locate.apple.com
(Service / iPhone)

It will take time to unlock your iPhone, but it's possible.